# Expressjs - AJAX not recognized by req.xhr

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, request

I have an action within my application where a user triggers a `DELETE` with an AJAX call to delete their account and is then redirected to the homepage with a message. The action occurs as expected, but the message does not appear. I can't use flash messages because I am destroying the session on deletion, so I decided to use an `if(req.xhr)` and pass an object with the view render if `true` and just the view if `false`. However, it doesn't appear that my route is recognizing the `X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest` from the `DELETE` and thus delivering the `else` statement. Can anyone point me to why that might be?

**Here is my route:**

```
siteRoutes.get('/', function(req, res) {    
    if(req.xhr) {
        console.log("AJAX request")
        res.render('pages/site/index.hbs',{
            successMessage: "Account was successfully deleted."
        });
    } else {
        console.log("Regular request") //Being triggered
        res.render('pages/site/index.hbs');
    }
});
```

**Here is my AJAX:**

```
$.ajax({
     method: 'DELETE',
     url: '/app/settings/account/delete',
     data: { successMessage: "Account was successfully deleted" },
     success: function(){
         window.location.replace('/');
     },
     error: function(error){
         console.log(error);
     }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

```
appRoutes.delete('/settings/account/delete', function(req, res){
return 
   ....
.then(function(){
            req.session.destroy();
            req.logout();
    })
```

Comment: Reverse proxy that isn't passing `X-Requested-With`?

Comment: @robertklep I'm sorry I'm not sure if I follow the connection to the reverse proxy. The `X-Requested-With` is coming from the `DELETE`

Comment: If you're using a reverse proxy, it needs to pass the `X-Requested-With` header (that the client sets) to Express.

Comment: I'm using the out of the box local server configuration, so I don't believe reverse proxy would come into play (maybe I'm wrong?). The only other thought I have are with security constraints around the `helmet` module and CSRF, but I don't know why that would block `req.xhr` from rendering a true statement

Comment: Oh, hang on: your example code is showing a `GET` route. Why would that be triggered for a `DELETE` request?

Comment: Sorry I actually forgot the `DELETE` route, which is triggered by the AJAX request and then redirects to the `GET`

Comment: You're "redirecting" in client-side code, which means you're telling the browser to load `/` as a regular page, _not_ through AJAX. So it's expected that `req.xhr` isn't set.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ajax function send method `DELETE`:

```
$.ajax({
      method: 'DELETE',
      url: '/app/settings/account/delete',
      data: { successMessage: "Account was successfully deleted" },
      success: function(){
            window.location.replace('/');
      },
      error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
      }
});
```

So you should change your route method to `delete` like this:

```
siteRoutes.delete('/', function(req, res) {

    if(req.xhr) { // It sure works
        console.log("AJAX request")
        res.render('pages/site/index.hbs',{
            successMessage: "Account was successfully deleted."
        });
    } else {
        console.log("Regular request") //Being triggered
        res.render('pages/site/index.hbs');
    }
});
```

Comment: I think the real issue is that after changing `window.location` (when the `DELETE` request has been completed), `req.xhr` is undefined (as expected, because _that_ request is not being made through `$.ajax()`)

Comment: @Burdy sorry for leaving out the `DELETE` method. I made an update to my question above to include the route.